# Theme.Holo is light on a user device

Tags: android, android-theme

My application uses Theme.Holo on SDK level 11+:

```
<application android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:description="@string/IDS_APPDESC"
    android:label="@string/IDS_APPTITLE"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App">

...
<resources>
   <style name="Theme.App" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>
```

In some places, I have hard-coded light colors, assuming that the background of Holo is dark. And here's a customer complaining that the text is unreadable because the background is white.

There's only one such customer; in general, the colors work. He claims his Android is vanilla 4.2.2, not a mod.

Is it really possible to redefine Holo like that on system level? How can an app detect and/or counter that?

Comment: "Is it really possible to redefine Holo like that on system level?" -- yes, though it should not have passed the CTS. Perhaps the user has pirated the Play Store, or the device manufacturer pirated the Play Store, and the device did not pass CTS.

Comment: I'm not worried much about the integrity of the Play Store :) We deliver via alternative stores, too. That said... Do you suspect this was done by a crazy mod builder, or by the user themselves?

Comment: "We deliver via alternative stores, too" -- if the device doesn't legitimately have the Play Store on it, the manufacturer does not have to honor the CTS and can modify `Theme.Holo.*`. They'd be stupid to do so, just because of problems like yours. "Do you suspect this was done by a crazy mod builder, or by the user themselves?" -- well, the user claims it isn't a mod. Conceivably the user rooted their device and used some sort of all-device theme changing app, as I think those things exist. Or, the manufacturer changed `Theme.Holo`.